# DesFire commands In PCSC readers

Tags: smartcard, mifare, smartcard-reader

I am trying to send Mifare DesFire (and Mifare Plus) APDUs to PCSC compliant readers. As I have read in the documentation you have to encapsulate those commands before sending them to those kind of readers. 
For example:

in DesFire the command 'Format PICC' is FC. You have to send either:
90 FC 00 00 00 which is the ISO - formatted command or 
FF DE 00 00 01 FC - the format FF DE 00 00 [Length_of_command] [command] is in the documentation of most PCSC readers

The problem is that the above format works fine only when the bytes of the response are more than one. If the response is one byte it always returns an unknown error code. E.g. if the FC command is sent as a first command it should return 'AE'. Instead I get an unknown error, which seems to be a problem of the reader.

Note: In the ISO-formatted command 90 FC 00 00 00 the response is correct ('91AE')

Comment: I think you are trying to send native commands using a method that uses/requires ISO 7816-4 Command/Response style APDU. What method do you use to access PCSC functionality?

Comment: So, is there any way to send native commands to PCSC readers ? 
Note that for Native commands that the response is more than one byte it works fine. 

If I send for example FF DE 00 00 02 0A 00 which is a request for authentication it responds to me normally !

Comment: @user2614870: hey maybe you can have answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740868/communicate-with-mifare-plus-security-level-1-2? thanks.